# Recover encrypted LVM

Tags: debian, lvm, partition, data-recovery, luks

I had Debian install running on LUKS encrypted LVM.

This morning, I wanted to install OS on external disk to be used on another host, but mistakenly I chose the wrong disk... Few seconds in I noticed that I have chosen the wrong one, so right away I stopped the process, but partition table already got written.

To recover I booted system rescue CD, and with the help of testdisk I recovered the partitions. However, I still couldn't boot my old setup, so I started looking for a way to recover the files at least. I ran rescue disk again, and I tried to mount it, but it fails with the following:

`# vgchange -v -ay worker1-vg`

WARNING: Device /dev/mapper/recoveryx has size of 444214667 sectors which is smaller than corresponding PV size of 486313984 sectors. Was device resized?
WARNING: One or more devices used as PVs in VG worker1-vg have changed sizes.
Activating logical volume worker1-vg/root.
activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for worker1-vg/root.
Creating worker1--vg-root
Loading table for worker1--vg-root (254:1).
device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (254:1) failed: Invalid argument
Removing worker1--vg-root (254:1)
Activating logical volume worker1-vg/swap_1.
activation/volume_list configuration setting not defined: Checking only host tags for worker1-vg/swap_1.
Creating worker1--vg-swap_1
Loading table for worker1--vg-swap_1 (254:1).
device-mapper: reload ioctl on  (254:1) failed: Invalid argument
Removing worker1--vg-swap_1 (254:1)
Activated 0 logical volumes in volume group worker1-vg.
0 logical volume(s) in volume group "worker1-vg" now active

Luckily the VG is detected, and I still have the LUKS header, but as can be seen in the above code blocks, activation fails due to "device-mapper: reload ioctl on (254:1) failed: Invalid argument"

Any ideas how to recover this partition?